# A simple way to create graphs of series and parallel networks?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, trees

I tried

```
TreePlot[{{G -> M, "p1"}, {M -> D, "p2"}}, Left, 
 VertexLabeling -> True]
```

I was hoping the graph would look like a horizontal linear series circuit, but it did not. Next,

```
TreePlot[{{G -> M, "p1"}, {M -> D, "p2"}}, Left, G, 
 VertexLabeling -> True]
```

was horizontal from left to right, but lost the edge labels. These were regained
with

```
TreePlot[{{G -> M, "p1"}, {M -> D, "p2"}}, Automatic, G, 
 VertexLabeling -> True]
```

but now horizontality was lost :)

Comment: What version are you using?  I ask because on a Mac with v12.2, your second example gives horizontal with vertex labels, which seems to be what you want.  Also, VertexLabeling is in red suggesting a problem.

Comment: Thanks, I'm using 11.3, and VertexLabels suggested by @MarcoB  is not yet available.  I'll need to find some other way, which works in 11.3  :)

Answer (score 2):

Specify one of the terminal nodes as the root and use `VertexLabels`, not `VertexLabeling`?

```
TreePlot[
  {{g -> m, "p1"}, {m -> d, "p2"}}, 
  Left,
  g, 
  VertexLabels -> Automatic
]
```

[image: linear plot]